# Errors after deleting an action using Unity's new input system

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity's new input system.  I recently deleted some actions, and now I'm getting the following error whenever I go into Play mode.  As [stated here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-find-action-on-xinputcontroller-error.946153/), the error doesn't break anything, but it's annoying to always see errors in my console.  Is there any way to refresh the input settings so that the actions I deleted are completely removed and this error goes away?

```
Cannot find action 'Camera/New action1' with ID 'af026e96-883f-4172-ba96-2d8225a11f0f' in 
    'PlayerInput (UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputActionAsset)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput:OnEnable() (at Library/PackageCache/
    com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.0/InputSystem/Plugins/PlayerInput/PlayerInput.cs:1564)
```

Comment: Unity usually has a remove on play error button in the console window, does it work for you?

Comment: @Stephan I don't want to remove all errors in the console, just these specific errors.  I don't know any way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Its just a bug in Unity, if you just go to any game object with player input, change default map to some other value and just change it back to original and save, the error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the object in the inspector, re-select it, and then re-save it then the error should stop.

Comment: I clicked the Auto-Save check box and then ran the game and I didn't get the error.  So then I unchecked Auto-Save and ran the game again and it's still fine.  Weird.  I guess clicking Save Asset does something differently than Auto Save.